# Why does incrementing a state variable result in an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Making a simple counter-example. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Ex2() {

    const [counter, setCounter ] = useState(0);

    const increaseValue = () => {
        setCounter(counter++);
    }

    const decreaseValue = () => {
        setCounter(counter--);
    }

    return (
        <div className="ex2">
            <p>{counter}</p>
            <p><button onClick={increaseValue}>increase</button><button onClick={decreaseValue}>Decrease</button></p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Please post errors as formatted text and not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setCounter(counter++);` and `setCounter(counter--);` are actually changing the variable at the end of the line as well, not giving you `counter + 1` and `counter - 1`, but it's a constant, so that error is thrown

Comment: yeah, but I thought `a++` and `a+1` are one and the same thing!

Comment: @Deadpool haha, not quite, there's also `++a` which will change the variable before it's accessed

Comment: @Deadpool No, one modifies `a`, one doesn’t.

Comment: So technically `--a` and` a--` change the variable, but `a-1` wont? How is that?

Comment: @Deadpool Why would it? Look up the JS `++` operator.

Answer (score 1):

`counter++` is an operation that is the logical equivalent of `counter = counter + 1`. It's attempting to *modify* the state value directly, which is prohibited in React.

`counter + 1` is an expression without assignment, so it's evaluated as a *new* value when passed to your `set` function.

That's the real problem with your code. However, the actual compilation error is because by incrementing the state value you're attempting to reassign a constant.

Comment: It’s not the modification of state that’s the error but that it’s a `const`. Modifying state directly is *legal*, just wrong.

Comment: True, but that's really secondary to the main problem. I'll revise to clarify that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are doing `counter++` which is trying to increase the counter with post increment operator `++` variable.

Remember to always use setter function to update your state.

There are a few ways you can update your counter by doing : `setCounter(counter+1)`
or use below callback approach

Below is the better approach using setState callback.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function App(props) {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const IncreaseValue = () => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
  }

  const DecreaseValue = () => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev - 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <p>{counter}</p>
       <p><button onClick={IncreaseValue}>increase</button><button onClick={DecreaseValue}>Decrease</button></p>
    </div>
  );
}
```